# #1054 - La columna 'ciudad' en field list es desconocida

Tags: php

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/xampp/htdocs/KangreSystem/proveedores.csv'
INTO TABLE proveedores
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(idProveedor,nombre,telefono,celular,email,ciudad)
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar cómo está constituida tu tabla `proveedores`? Parece que no hay en ella una columna llamada `ciudad`